# Call function within an event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I call a function once an event has finished? IE -

```
    $('.class').slideUp('fast', function() { 
        // run function
    });
```

Comment: Hm... exactly like that? http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: It wasn't working because it wasn't a global function! I had it right in the first place :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the function reference:

```
$('.class').slideUp('fast', yourFunction);
```

Comment: Ah, it wasn't working because it wasn't a global function. NVM - fixed now!

Comment: How could I not think of that?!?!  :)  +1

Answer (score 4):

Is it a global function?  If so, *just call it*

```
$('.class').slideUp('fast', function() { 
    yourFunction();
});
```

Comment: You don't even need to make a lambda, just `$('.class').slideUp('fast', yourFunction);` will work as long as you don't need to pass anything to the function.

Comment: @Tacroy - for sure.  Blender already put that though, so I'd recommend upvoting him :)

Comment: I started writing that comment before he wrote his answer, I just had to double check how you do inline code in comments :(

Comment: @Tacroy - no prob at all.  One more upvote and he'll be the top answer, as he should be.  Can't believe I didn't think to add that...

Comment: Note that the question doesn't say whether the function to be called has parameters, so at least doing it like this will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function runThisFunction(){
   //Do Stuff
}
$('.class').slideUp('fast', function() { 
    runThisFunction();
});
```